# How to install Apricity on a logical volume using Calamares?

Tags: linux, system-installation, lvm

I am trying to replace Fedora which I have installed on one of the logical volumes with Apricity (Gnome version), but when the Calamares graphical installer gets to partitioning, it only shows a LVM partition as a whole and does not allow me to select a logical volume on that partition.

Is installation on a logical volume unsupported at the moment or should I do something to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, installation to an LVM logical volume is not supported by Calamares. See https://calamares.io/bugs/browse/CAL-226

Apricity is based on Arch Linux, so there's a good chance Apricity can *boot* from an LVM logical volume. But it has to be installed to a partition due to the installer's limitations.